# How can I send my friend this .jar file?

Tags: java, image, jar, export

I have been able to do this before with simpler programs, I just exported the project to a runnable .jar and it worked fine.

Every time my friend tries to open the program it keeps throwing the error messages that I put in place saying that, in general, it can't load the Images that I have added. I have put my images in a separate folder that I turned into a build path or whatever.

In the program I reference the images like so:

```
 BufferedImage img= ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img.png"));
```

I am using eclipse if that helps. Should I just take the images out of the 'res' folder and just put it in the original 'src' folder?

If anyone has any advice it will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you are sending him the JAR file just fine.  That's not the problem at all.  Please update your question title to match what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image must be inside the **src** folder.

Put it inside the src folder, refresh the project in Eclipse and use

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img.png"));
```

If the image is inside a package, use

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/PACKAGE/img.png"));
```

if it still doesn't work, try using getResource instead of getResourceAsStream

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img.png"));
```